# Creating array of text boxes dynamically using javascript and accessing text box names from php to pass data to mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a simple form with a text box. The user is able to add more text boxes by clicking a button.
I am dynamically creating the text boxes using javascript, however I have 2 issues:
1- I am not sure how to access the text boxes from the PHP file. 
2- Whenever I click +addmore button on my html page it creates new text boxes but it clears the value of the previous ones.

Below is the html part:

```
<input type="text" id="program" name="program[]">     //Initital text box
<div><a onclick="CreateTxt()">+Add More</a></div>   //Add more button
<input type="hidden" id="hid" name="hid" value="0">
<input type="submit" value="Next" name="submit1">
```

Below is javascript part:

```
var i = 1; // Global counter
var hidden_field; 

function CreateTxt(){

var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
y.setAttribute("type", "text");
y.setAttribute("Name", "program" + i);   //I am sure this is not working for the array names
y.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
document.getElementById('userdata1').innerHTML += 
'<label for="program"><br />Program</label>';

document.getElementById('userdata1').appendChild(y);
hidden_field = document.getElementById("hid").value = i;  //passing the number of created textboxes
i++;
}
```

Below is PHP part:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('connection.php');

$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$i = $_POST['hid'];

if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){

if($i > 0){ //It means more than one text box exist

    $program = [];

    for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++){
        $program[$j] = $_POST['program'][$j];

        $sql = $db->prepare ("UPDATE user SET program = ?, WHERE id = ? ");
        $sql->bind_param("ss", $program[$j], $id);
        $sql->execute();
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('userdata1')` I don't see any element with id `userdata1`

Comment: I have it but I did not copy the entire file in order to make the code shorter: <div class="form-field"  id="userdata1">
     </div>

Comment: if name is set dynamically as `"program" + i`, you'll retrieve in `$_POST['program' . $j]`, not `$_POST['program'][$j]`

Comment: Thanks Cid. I dont believe it was that simple, the PHP part works fine now. What about the text boxes being emptied every time I add another?

Comment: The existing fields getting cleared, is due to your use of `.innerHTML += …`. This first _reads_ the current innerHTML of the target element - but that does not contain the values entered by the user. By overwriting the innerHTML, you are _re-creating_ these fields. Create and append the label the same way as you did with the input, instead of using innerHTML.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, your tip was very helpful. It works fine now.